# Snowflake Snowpro Certifiction

Tags: certificate, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I worked on Vertica, IBM IAS that are MPP databases. They are similar to Redshift; I've been reading Snowflake documentation lately.

Can anyone suggest how to take Snowpro Certification without real time project experience? Snowflake conducts classroom/online training but they are expensive for me. Does anyone know if any online trainings are available targeting the certification exam?

Appreciate your response.

Thank you,
Prashanth.

Answer (score 2):

Snowflake does offer some completely free self-directed and on-demand training as well. Here are some resources to get you started:
https://community.snowflake.com/s/education-services
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/other-resources.html

Comment: I really appreciate the information you provided Suzy, thank you. Do you think its sufficient to clear Snowpro certification? Otherwise, do you know of any directed online training for this certification exam like acloud.guru, linuxacademy for AWS etc. I do not have real-time project experience in using Snowflake, so I thought certification would help me in changing my job that is using Snowflake technology.

Comment: Yes, these are good resources, but here's the official link to the page and more resources as needed:
https://community.snowflake.com/s/snowprocertifications

Comment: Thank you Suzy for the information, really appreciate it!

Comment: @Rachel - I'm not sure if any other comprehensive online training available that is not as much costly as Snowflake is charging. Like for example, for AWS/Google/Azure cloud certifications, acloud.guru and Linux Academy charges much less for their certification courses compared to what Amazon/Google/MS charges for their trainings. I'm still searching for something similar.

Comment: Prashanth, not all of the trainings are required to set up a test. Have you already seen the on demand or self directed offerings: https://community.snowflake.com/s/education-services

Answer (score 2):

you can sign up for a trial account and get $400 in free credits over 30 days as well to play with it.  https://www.snowflake.com/trial_faqs/ - this is actually quite a lot if you do not upsize and/or leave a large box on for a long time.  snowflake will be much simpler to use than all of those databases.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake’s SnowPro Core Certification is now available! Very excited to launch our 1st level which certifies someone’s knowledge in implementing and migrating to @SnowflakeDB. For more information about the certification exam and how to prepare, visit: https://community.snowflake.com/s/snowprocertifications

Answer (score 0):

1. Go over Snowflake Blog Posts and introduction videos on YouTube
2. Sign up for Zero-to-Snowflake online workshop
3. Start Snowflake trial and try what you've seen in those videos

Comment: Thank you AskMeAboutData

Answer (score -2):

Dont take up this exam,
These people doesnt have transparent process in conducting exam.

They will suspend the exam in the middle and give some silly reasons to charge more money from you.

Please see my linkedin post on the same and you can message me for more details on this snowflake scam.

[Snowflake scam Linkedin Post](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/hoysal_snowflake-snowflakedb-snowflakedb-activity-6620050718743191552-KTBi)