# Snowflake SnowPro Certification

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Anyone cleared Snowflake's SnowPro Certification? I need help with and information about what did you do in order to prepare for this certification. I appreciate your information.

Thank you,
Prashanth.

Comment: you asked this question 16 days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58458062/snowflake-snowpro-certifiction

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Snowflake Snowpro Certifiction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58458062/snowflake-snowpro-certifiction)

Answer (score 3):

Snowflake did officially launch the SnowPro Core Certification publicly on Tuesday, October 29th.

To view more information about the SnowPro Core Certification, you can navigate to https://community.snowflake.com/s/snowprocertifications.

Comment: Thank you Seeling. I did go through this link, I was actually looking for help on if anyone passed the certification and what did they do to do it. For example, for AWS/Azure/Google cloud certifications, there are online courses offered by acloud. guru, Linux Academy etc. I'm looking for something that covers each topic that is targeted in the exam and that is why looking for help. I never worked on Snowflake, but have some working experience on databases like Vertica, IBM IAS MPP databases.

Comment: Snowflake offers ILT courses at this point.  The course Snowflake Fundamentals (4-days with labs) is the foundational course that covers broad set of key topics in Snowflake.  For individual or small teams, they can look for signing up for either the public one (at one of the delivery cities) or purely virtual delivery.  All are still instructor-led at this point.  More info can be found at:  https://www.snowflake.com/education-training/training/

Answer (score 0):

No. They dont have transparent process for certification.

First, They have only online proctoring exam, they wont even give option to choose test center on your own.

But when you start the online exam by agreeing to all their conditions (arranging external usb camera, high speed internet etc) they will suspend or stop it by giving some silly reason and tell you to choose test centre by paying $100 more.

Later when you question back they will edit the requirement document itself and tell you are not meeting the requirements. (PFA sample of their requirement change)
Funny thing is they dont even know where is their Server.

It is one of the rubbish process I have seen, Please dont take up this certification and get trapped like me.

[Portland OR is mentioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1s9Co.png)

[Phoenix Arizona is mentioned later](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbWi7.png)